# Run new Magento ImportExport from shell

Tags: magento-1.9, importexport

does anyone have an idea, how it's possible to run the new ImportExport profile (e.g. for products or customer export) from shell?

I don't mean dataflow, but the new export routine from Mage_ImportExport module.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box no you do not have a shell script that can do this. However, you can extend the shell scripts to implement your own import requirement.

I have been using the Danslo API Import which I belive is based on the one you wish to make use of so you should be able to do something very similar to this.

`class My_Module_Import extends Mage_Shell_Abstract {
public function run() { $api = Mage::getModel('api_import/import_api'); $api->importEntitites(/* removed code */); 
}`

You will need to replace the model to the core one, and review the import functionality for the exact format that is required.

As I mentioned this is the one which I am making use of for this: https://github.com/danslo/ApiImport It may be worth reviewing how it wraps down to the core for reference when building your own.

Comment: Thank you - I'll have a look on that. My experience until now was, that it's generally better to do extensive import/export and other database-related operations on the local machine. So it's probably a good idea to dump the Magento instance completely to a local server, set some exorbitant memory_limit, max_execution_time values etc. and do the whole job in browser there.